# JQuery UIのAutocompleteで表示されないレコードがある

Tags: javascript, jquery, 正規表現, array

ウェブプログラミング初心者です。JQuery UIのAutocompleteでユーザー入力文字と同じ文字が配列に含まれる場合、そのレコードを表示したいと思っています。

一致するレコードのいくつかは表示されるのですが、データベースと照らし合わせたところ表示されていないレコードがあります。

customFilterをデバッグしたところ、`array`には正しいリストが渡されており`term`にも入力したテキストボックスの値が格納されています。

```
function customFilter(array, terms) {
    arrayOfTerms = terms.split(" ");
    var term = $.map(arrayOfTerms, function (tm) {
         return $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(tm);
    }).join('|');
   var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
    return $.grep(array, function (value) {
       return matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value);
    });
};

$( "#frmCode" ).autocomplete({
  multiple: true,
  mustMatch: false,
  minLength: 2,
  source: function (request, response) {
    response(customFilter(
    availableCode, request.term));
  }
});
```

こちらも試してみましたが、解決できませんでした。

```
var a = $.grep(array, function(value){
  var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
  return matcher.test(value);
});
```

どなたかアドバイスを頂けますでしょうか。宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: > こちらも試してみましたが、解決できませんでした。
>
> var a = $.grep(autoData, function(value){
> var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
> return matcher.test(term);
> }); `matcher.test(term)`でなく`matcher.test(value)`ですか？ 例えばフィルター対象が`availableCode`だったり`autoData`だったりと変数が安定しておらず、第三者からは何を操作しているのかよくわかりません。質問者さんは把握できているのでしょうか？

Comment: @sayuriさん　別のテストページを作成してそこからコピーしたため変数が異なる形となり困惑を招き申し訳ありませんでした。メインの質問の全体のコード内の変数は互い違いになっていなかったと思います。

Comment: var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");
から
var matcher = new RegExp("" + term, "i");
に変更することにより問題なく動作するようになりました。ありがとうございました。

console.log("result - " + matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value));
console.log("value - " + value)
でコンソール出力したところ、予想通りの結果を表示していることも確認できています。

Comment: @Chrissa 問題が解決した場合には[自己回答](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1747/754)をお願いできますでしょうか。同じ問題に当たった人の参考になります。

Comment: @YukiInoue 初めての質問だったため不適切な回答方法ですみませんでした。そしてアドバイスありがとうございます。自己回答させていただきました。

Comment: @Chrissa 問題解決したようで何よりです。  そして、できれば回答を「承認」していただけると、システム的に解決済みとして扱われるのでお願いできますでしょうか: 回答の隣のチェックボックスをクリックすることで、承認できます。

Comment: @YukiInoue ご丁寧な回答ありがとうございます。早速承認しました。今後質問投稿する際の参考になるので助かりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + term, "i");` 
から 
`var matcher = new RegExp("" + term, "i");` 
に変更することにより問題なく動作するようになりました。ありがとうございました。

`console.log("result - " + matcher.test(value.label || value.value || value));

 console.log("value - " + value)` 
でコンソール出力したところ、予想通りの結果を表示していることも確認できています。

アドバイスくださったみなさま、ありがとうございました。